# How to slow down the milliseconds between my json calls?

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using [this script](https://script.google.com/d/Mg7e3sb6exgf-h3YQVAWAubkHX3xEP0vk/edit?mid=ACjPJvF1KiaraAqyy3Gua-UR46oh1lVt2vEU1qFzjo-9MJVWyDlujQEeMrwsKek5zbk7WrZare7Fz9OipiMVkDen3obJM-kxiLe4QuN5-AIHbv5dUBR2o8tUT1e8matL3g6706KB-usj9g&uiv=2) to call a few hundred endpoints at Seatgeek. To avoid having Seatgeek throttle me for over-usage, how do I slow down the milliseconds between each call?

I only need the call to run twice/day and have no idea where to look to see how frequently I'm hitting their data. My concern is I get cut off before I figure out what's going on - help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add Some Log statements instead of invoking actual endpoint to see how frequent you are processing
2. For just slowing down, you can introduce sleep (You might be able to find similar thing in your language of choice)
3. Or rather schedule the script at whichever interval you want it to run. Crontabs or full-blown schedulers like Apache Airflow/ControlM/Jenkins etc can be leveraged

Comment: Thanks @so-random-dude - I ended up going with a version of option three where I placed the =importjson() in a column, then scripted the last part of the concatenated formula to paste and complete the url endpoint--I capture the data--then the script removes the piece. This way I only call each of the ~1100 endpoints once a day (when the script runs).